# Why do I get HTTP Error 403.14 if I add a class to C# .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET Website and everything was fine until I tried to put some code for a HttpWebRequest into a separate class file. I am confused why that happened because everything was okay before. Could someone explain this to me?

This is the code that works just fine (Please keep in mind that I'm still a beginner):

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const string HOST = "server";
    public RemoteCertificateValidationCallback ServerCertificateValidationCallback { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   }

    protected void Button1_Click(Object sender1, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(string.Format("https://{0}/authenticate", HOST));
            request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            string token1 = Convert.ToString(textBoxUsername.Text);
            string token2 = Convert.ToString(textBoxPassword.Text);
            bool t1 = (token1.Contains("<") || token1.Contains(">") || token1.Contains("&") || token1.Contains("%") || token1.Contains("\"") || token1.Contains("'")) == true;
            bool t2 = (token2.Contains("<") || token2.Contains(">") || token2.Contains("&") || token2.Contains("%") || token2.Contains("\"") || token2.Contains("'")) == true;

            if (t1 == true) { Label3.Visible = true; ;  }
            if (t2 == true) { Label3.Visible = true; ;  }

            if ((t1 == false) && (t2 == false))
            {
                Label3.Visible = false;
                string postData = @"somestring" + token1 + token2;

                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(response.StatusCode);
                    TextBox2.Text = (responseFromServer);
                    TextBox1.Text = responseFromServer.Substring(821, 36);
                    reader.Close();
                    dataStream.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                TextBox2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

So if I try to put the whole request body and so on in another lass file I get the **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden** error when loading the page.

Can someone tell me why? I can provide more Code if needed. Thank you in advance.

Edit: Here is the code not working. Ehen I noticed that it did not work with my original code, I tried to make a simple code witha class file to see if the error was within my code but that also didn't work. So this Code just should show the connection string in a textbox on the website. This is the Webform.aspx.css:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 trial = new Class1();
        TextBox1.Text = trial.wholeText();
    }
}
```

This is the Webfrm.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Classtries15.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="188px" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="420px"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Class.cs:

```
public class Class1
{
     WebForm1 target;

    string token1 = "email";
    string token2 = "password";


    public string wholeText()
    {
        string postData = @"SomeConectionstring" + token1 + token2;

        return postData;
    }
```

Funnily enough, when I tried it again a few minutes ago it worked so now I'm really confused.

Edit2: It gave me the error again.

Comment: We need the code that does not work to help you. Please edit the question with the code that ***is not*** working and explain what part is not working.

Comment: I think you broke your ASP.net `Class to Form Mapping`. Also it's pretty unclear what do you try to achieve. Do you have a full repository of the project, which you can share?

Comment: @Smartis Basically I had a ASP.net site where I could just click one button and it'd make some webrequests to a server. The code worked fine when it was all in one file, and it also worked when I put the request code in aclass but sometimes I'd get the descibed error. Later my supervisor explained why that happened when he took a look at the site. I don' recall in detail but I think it had something to do with the webbrowser (I use firefox) searching for a 'default file' or so. So we renamed the files to default.aspx and default.aspx.cs and ever since I've never had the error again.

Comment: @Smartis Sorry for the long story, I hope you get what I mean :)

Comment: @Laura The default route of an WebApplication can be configured in ASP.net. But I think your supervisor is referring to default behavior of resolving URLs.
Anyway, is this question still open? If yes, whats the question? ;)

Comment: @Smartis Like I mentioned, we resolved the issue through renaming the files. Thank you tho :)